# fork..join in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, fork-join

I am trying to achieve req ##[3:5]ack using fork..join. I am able to run logic for req##[5]ack. But I am unable to run for req ##[3:5]ack.

I am trying-

```
wait(req)
    fork:check_ack
        begin
        wait(ack)
        $display("Ack passed");
        end

        begin
        repeat(5)
        @(posedge clk);
        $display("Ack failed");
        end

        begin
        repeat(3)
        @(posedge clk);
        $display("Ack failed");
        end
    join_any
    disable check_ack;
```

I need to somehow continue to check after 3 cycles also.

Comment: this is an assertion, why not use an sva for this?

Comment: @Serge Yes this is an assertion. I was given the task of trying it with nested fork..join.

Comment: actually your assertion `req##[3:5]ack` does not make much sense. It means that 'req' must be true and ack must be true (though it could start 3 to 5 cycles) after req.  I guess you wanted something like `req |-> ##[3:5] ack` or even something like `$rose(req) |-> ##...` Can you verify you exact intention?

Comment: @Serge Yes the intention is generating _req |-> ##[3:5] ack_

Comment: This is a complicated case. I do not think that you can really solve it in a conventional verilog. The way the assertion is theoretically implemented, it starts 3 threads for every clock edge while 'req' is high with corresponding delays and fail if any one of the threads fails. It sounds like dynamic threading not existent in verilog. You would need to go to svtb side or do it in 'c/c++'.  It would be easier to track just the posedge of' 'req'

Comment: Yes @Serge, it's a complicated case. Thanks for your inputs. I will try in c/c++.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a state bit that indicates when you are inside the range.

```
bit in_range;
@(posedge clk iff req);
fork
   begin
     in_range = 0;
     @(posedge clk iff ack) if (in_range) $display("passes"); 
                            else $display("fails");
   end
   begin
      repeat(3) @(posedge clk) ;
      in_range <='1;
      wait(0);
   end
   begin
     repeat(5) @(posedge clk);
     $display("fails");
   end
join_any
disable fork;
```

Comment: Thanks @dave_59, it works. However, I was trying with nested fork..join.

Comment: You are not making any sense. That is the first mention of any nesting

Comment: Yes It doesn't make any sense to try assertion like this, but I was given the task of trying with fork join.